# ArrayList in java not removing -1

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

So, I've been in a competition.

The question is I have to print out the 3rd smallest positive integer from an array of inputs. ignoring the negative integers and zero. so the sorted array must start at 1. not 0.

This is what input looks like.

5

1 10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

2 3 -10 9 8

3 2 0 5

4 5 -2 -1 0 1 2

5 1 -1

first line of input is amount of datasets. it this case it's 5. and the rest are array of integers.

first and second integer of each array are the array number and the amount of elements. the rest are the actual array. i.e. 5 1 -1. 5 is array number 5, 1 is there is only 1 element and -1 is the element.

if there is less than 3 elements in the array. print "na".
that's what it should look like (results from input above).
if there's more than 3 sorted elements in the array. then print out the array number. seperated by a space and then the 3rd smallest number in the array.

1 3
na
na
na
na

but I get 
1 3
na
na
4 2
na

and when I print out the 4th sorted array. I get [-1, 1, 2]. The 0 is being removed but not -1. and I don't really understand. is there any way to fix this? or it's just that I needed more skills.

```
public class one {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int dataset = in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine();
        for (int y = 0; y < dataset; y++) {
            int index = in.nextInt();
            int times = in.nextInt();
            ArrayList<Integer> stt = new ArrayList<>(times);
            int ct = 0;
            while (true) {
                int i = in.nextInt();
                stt.add(i);
                ct++;
                if (ct == times) {break;}
            }
            Collections.sort(stt);
            for (int d = 0; d < stt.size(); d++) {
                if (stt.get(d) <= 0) {stt.remove(d);}
            }
            System.out.println(stt);
            if (y + 1 == dataset) {
                if (stt.size() < 3) {System.out.print("na");}
                else {System.out.print((y + 1) + " " + stt.get(2));}
            }
            else {
                if (stt.size() < 3) {System.out.println("na");}
                else {System.out.println((y + 1) + " " + stt.get(2));}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to @Eran's suggestion is to count downwards.

So to recap the issue:

1. you have list `[-1,-2,3]`, and start a loop, `d=0`
2. you check `[-1,-2,3][d=0] = -1 <= 0`, and remove it, `[-2,3]` is the new list, and `d++` means `d=1`
3. you check `[-2,3][d=1] = 3 <= 0`, keep it, list remains `[-2,3]`, `d++` means `d=2`
4. loop exits

You can fix that keeping the index unchanged when an item is removed (practically adding `d--` as suggested), or just address the issue caused by checking the part of the list which can change (everything towards the end) with checking the part of the list which has not changed for sure.

```
for (int d = stt.size()-1; d >= 0; d--) {
    if (stt.get(d) <= 0) {
        stt.remove(d);
    }
}
```

Then the steps will look like

1. `[-1,-2,3]` and `d=2` (note the `size()-1`, that is important)
2. check `[-1,-2,3][d=2] = 3 <= 0`, do not do anything, `d--` means `d=1`
3. check `[-1,-2,3][d=1] = -2 <= 0`, new list is `[-1,3]`, `d--` results in `d=0`
4. check `[-1,3][d=0] = -1 <= 0`, new list is `[3]`, `d--` results in `d=-`
5. loop exits (note the `d>=0`, that is important too, we do want to check the 0th element, and exit at `d=-1` only)

Minor added benefit is that `size()` is called only once (at initialization time).

Answer (score 4):

I would use `list.removeIf()` method before sort since it saves you time and lines, plus you have no worries for the `ConcurrentModificationException`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 8, -3, 5, -6, -12, 5, -12, -95, -32, 0, 3, 9);
    list = new ArrayList<>(list); //Make the list modifiable. Ignore this
    list.removeIf(i -> i <= 0); //Remove negatives and 0s
    Collections.sort(list);
    System.out.println(list);
    if (list.size() >= 3)
        System.out.println(list.get(2));
    else
        System.out.println("na");
}
```

Outputs to:

```
[1, 3, 5, 5, 8, 9]
5
```

And as expected, with input: `[-1, -8, -3, -5, -6, -12, 5, -12, -95, -32, 0, -3, 9]` prints out:

```
[5, 9]
na
```

Comment: I gotta look into that skills. I've just finished some array implementation questions on hackerRank. And now I'm moving on to ArrayList before my semester starts next month on OOP. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @grindarius No problem! Take also a look at [what should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3):

You problem is in this loop:

```
for (int d = 0; d < stt.size(); d++) {
    if (stt.get(d) <= 0) {stt.remove(d);}
}
```

Removing an element from a List decrements the index of the remaining elements following that element. Therefore, each time you remove the element whose index is `d`, you later skip the element whose index was `d+1` and became `d` after the removal.

You can fix it by decrementing the index after each removal:

```
for (int d = 0; d < stt.size(); d++) {
    if (stt.get(d) <= 0) {
        stt.remove(d);
        d--;
    }
}
```